# @Output emit value from directive to parent component Angular 4

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

I have some upload directive, that is very simple, only problem is that i have to emit value from this directive component to parent component. Does anybody know a simple solution? Thanks in advance. This is my directive for now:

**upload-field.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { TooltipModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tooltip';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-upload-field',
  templateUrl: './upload-field.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./upload-field.component.scss']
})
export class UploadFieldComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() labelName: string;
  @Input() placeHolderValue: string;
  value = '';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  uploadButton(event: any) {
    this.value += event.target.value;
    this.value = this.value.replace(/^.*\\/, '');
  }

}
```

**upload-field.component.html**

```
<input placeholder="{{placeHolderValue}}" disabled="disabled" class="form-control first-input" value="{{value}}" />
<div class="file-upload">
  <span class="btn btn-default btn-lg">{{labelName}}</span>
  <input type="file" class="form-control upload-button" (change)="uploadButton($event)" value="{{value}}" />
</div>
```

And I use it like this:

```
<app-upload-field [labelName]="'Blader'" [placeHolderValue]="'Kies bestand'"></app-upload-field>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `EventEmitter` for this.

Reference: **[Parent listens for child event](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event)**

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  //...your decorator properties
})
export class UploadFieldComponent { 
    @Output() onValueChanged = new EventEmitter<any>();

    uploadButton() {
       this.value += event.target.value;
       this.value = this.value.replace(/^.*\\/, '');
       this.onValueChanged.emit(this.value);
    }

}
```

In parent component,
Template:

```
<app-upload-field [labelName]="'Blader'" [placeHolderValue]="'Kies bestand'" 
    (onValueChanged)=onValueChanged($event)>
</app-upload-field>
```

Within component code,

```
 onValueChanged(value) {
       // value will be the emitted value by the child
 }
```

> The child component exposes an `EventEmitter` property with which it
>   emits events when something happens. The parent binds to that event
>   property and reacts to those events.

Comment: This is not good, Unable to resolve signature on property decorator when called as expression

Comment: @MiomirDancevic oh, that whas a typo. I missed the brackets for `@Output()`, did you checked the **Angular reference link** I provided?

Comment: @Paritosh can the uploadButton() trigger inside the parent component?

Comment: @SnowBases - not getting ur ques. you want to call `uploadButton` from its parent component? than yes, you can do it using `ViewChild` property attribute, https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-viewchild/ - use this to have child component's object and then call public methods of child component

Answer (score 0):

In **UploadFieldComponent**

```
export class UploadFieldComponent implements OnInit {
...
@Output myValueChanged = new  EventEmitter<string>();//passing a string value to parent
...
  uploadButton(event: any) {
    ...
    myValueChanged.emit(valueToBePassed);
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<app-upload-field [labelName]="'Blader'" (myValueChanged)="parentEvent($event)" [placeHolderValue]="'Kies bestand'"></app-upload-field>
```

**In parent component**

```
 parentEvent(data:string){
    // do something with data
    }
```

Refer [this](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event) link for more details.

Comment: You have mentioned `[myValueChanged]="parentEvent($event)"` in your code, which is incorrect. `[myValueChanged]` is an event, you should use round brackets instead: `(myValueChanged)`